# Can not resolve symbol for dagger component in android

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to add Dagger2 to my project in Android Studio.

This is my dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

I am following this example.

```
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2#advantages
```

I am getting this error.

Can not resolve symbol DaggerNetComponent

I tried changing dependencies and other solution found after googling. but no luck.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: In my case, the name of the component while building (with Dagger prefixed) was perfect, still it throws error. After making sure the component is really generated after build, I just removed the component name and added the same again..then it worked. Looks silly but that is how it is fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

The DaggerNetComponent is generated after compilation. You should enable annotation processing in compilation to generate that file. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642712/enable-annotation-processors-option-in-android-studio-2-2) has the details.

These generated file should be added to the source path of the project to get recognized.