# annotationprocessor and apt configure equivalent

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations, android-apt, annotation-processor

I'm using `AndroidAnnotaion`, but due to Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 2.3.0, they said `android-apt` was obsoleted. And `annotationProcessor` is a new one. so, I want to know how can I configure `annotationProcessor` like I do with `apt` before.

If I misunderstand something, please help.

**So, before...**

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies {

    def AAVersion = '4.2.0'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        library 'true'
    }
}
```

**and now...**

```
dependencies {

    def AAVersion = '4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

Comment: Did you check the migration guide? https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

Comment: Looks like you need to configure arguments, like you did with `android-apt`.

Comment: @botteaap yeah...

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, nope I will check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass annotation processing configuration options in the following way:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments = ['library': 'true']
      }
    }
  }
}
```