# Couldn't use Annotation processors in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build, android-studio-2.3, annotation-processor

I recently updated my Android Studio version to 2.3. Everything works fine but except the problem that I am facing with AnnotationProcessor support in the `build.gradle`.

**What I am Intended to do:**

I want to use Annotation based Permission Dispatcher library in my project but I couldn't able to successfully build my project since gradle throwing following build errors

```
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**My Code:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            /* Couldn't import MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher 
            import in my code since it is throwing error as stated above */

            MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);

        }
    }
```

**My** `build.gradle`:

```
ext{
    permissionDispatcherVersion = '2.3.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:$permissionDispatcherVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:$permissionDispatcherVersion"
}
```

**What I tried:**

I tried enabling Annotation processors in Android Studio preferences as shown below suggestions found on [enable Annotation Processors option in Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642712/enable-annotation-processors-option-in-android-studio-2-2)

[image]

Any sort of clue or suggestions would be very helpful. I have been stuck with this issue for more than 2 days since I couldn't able to find any workaround. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you solve it? My only solution for now is adding kotlin and applying the kotlin plugin, this makes the annotation processors run...

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Build->Clean Project` and then `Build->Rebuild Project`.
You might also wanna try `./gradlew --refresh -dependencies`