# Getting apt error while upgrading to gradle 3.0 version in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, apt

I want to update my project to run in android studio 3.0. While updating I'm getting an error with `apt`. I changed my complete `build.gradle` means all compile to implementation. Here is my `build.gradle` file.

Here is my error:

> Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'servlet-api'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

   }
   configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation project(':androidHorizontalListView')
implementation project(':library')
implementation project(':simpl3r')



implementation  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
implementation  files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
implementation  files('libs/bugsense-3.6.jar')
implementation  files('libs/espresso-1.1-bundled.jar')
implementation  files('libs/sample-2.4.1.jar')
implementation  files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
implementation  files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
implementation  files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
implementation  files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar')
implementation  files('libs/volley.jar')
implementation  files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation  files('libs/gcm.jar')
implementation  files('libs/mint-5.2.1.jar')
implementation project(':swipelibrary')


implementation  files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
implementation  files('libs/glide-3.7.0-javadoc.jar')
implementation  'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
implementation  'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7'
implementation  'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
implementation  'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation  'com.thefinestartist:utils:0.9.1'
apt 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'
implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
implementation  'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
implementation  'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
implementation  'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

//implemented retrofit.
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
implementation  'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

implementation  'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
implementation  'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
implementation project(':sample-chat')


implementation  'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.1.0'
implementation  "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"


implementation project(':sample-core')

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible plugins for android-apt after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574803/incompatible-plugins-for-android-apt-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

You enable annotation processing via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38698186/4624156), then you can delete the line

`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

and replace

`apt 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'`

with

`annotationProcessor 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'`

Comment: if i change like that iam getting this errror............Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Did you check the log? Try opening the Gradle console in the bottom right of Android Studio and read the red text. You may have to follow the stack trace to the first error that appears. There are other questions on StackOverflow that fix this problem such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove below line from your project's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

2) Replace : `apt 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'`

with

```
annotationProcessor 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'
```

3) Go to your gradle.properties write the below code and sync your project:
`android.enableAapt2=false`

for resolving com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error